# Activate vicious.widgets.net widget only if interface is available

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I have the following widget using `vicious` in my `rc.lua`:

```
-- Initialize widget Ethernet
ethwidget = wibox.widget.textbox()                                                                                                                            
-- Register widget       
    vicious.register(ethwidget, vicious.widgets.net, 'Eth0: <span color="#CC9933">down: ${eth0 down_kb} kB/s</span> <span color="#7F9F7F"> up: ${eth0 up_kb}  kB/s</span><span color="#cccccc"> [ ${eth0 rx_gb} GB //  ${eth0 tx_gb} GB ] | </span>', 2)
```

The thing is that I have a recent macbook pro, and if I don't have plugged  the [ethernet adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD463LL/A/thunderbolt-to-gigabit-ethernet-adapter), then I only see e.g. `${eth0 down_kb}` printed on my wibox. How could I add a conditional so that the widget is inserted only if the ethernet adapter is plugged?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came with a solution that is working fine. I found this link http://awesome.naquadah.narkive.com/wpn4XSWl/netwidget-with-two-interfaces and my code is as follows now:

```
eths = { 'eth0', 'wlp3s0' }
netwidget = wibox.widget.textbox()
vicious.register( netwidget, vicious.widgets.net,
function(widget,args)
t=''  
for i = 1, #eths do
e = eths[i]       
if args["{"..e.." carrier}"] == 1 then
    if e == 'wlp3s0' then
        t=t..'|'..'Wifi: <span color="#CC9933"> down: '..args['{'..e..' down_kb}']..' kbps</span>  <span color="#7F9F7F">up: ' ..args['{'..e..' up_kb}']..'   kbps </span>'..'[ '..args['{'..e..' rx_gb}'].. ' GB // ' ..args['{'..e..' tx_gb}']..' GB ] '
    else          
        t=t..'|'..'Eth0: <span color="#CC9933"> down: '..args['{'..e..' down_kb}']..' kbps</span>  <span color="#7F9F7F">up: ' ..args['{'..e..' up_kb}']..'   kbps </span>'..'[ '..args['{'..e..' rx_gb}'].. ' GB // ' ..args['{'..e..' tx_gb}']..' GB ] '
    end
end
end               
if string.len(t)>0 then -- remove leading '|'
return string.sub(t,2,-1)
end               
return 'No network'
end                                                                                                                                                           
, 1 )
```

And the you add your widget as follows (I am on awesome v3.5.9 (Mighty Ravendark)):

```
bottom_layout:add(netwidget)
```